# Add specify text to other line in notepad++

Tags: xml

Hello I have this lines in xml, because there are a lot of lines I will show only few items.

```
  <client_title>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>light_title01</name></client_title>
  <client_title>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>light_title02</name></client_title>
  <client_title>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>light_title03</name></client_title>
  <client_title>
```

but I want on every `</client_title>` to go down so to have something like that

```
  <client_title>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>light_title01</name>
  </client_title>
  <client_title>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>light_title02</name>
  </client_title>
  <client_title>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>light_title03</name>
  </client_title>
  <client_title>
```

there is any command or seach expression?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your question is even in the right place, but this should help.

Choose the `ReplaceAll` menu and select `Extended` as the Search Mode from the bottom.
Then replace `</name>` with `</name>\r\n`